# Geometry Problem Via Pidgen Hole Principle

Tags: geometry

Suppose a triangle can be placed inside a square of unit area in such a way that the center of the square is not inside the triangle. Show that one side of the triangle has length less than $1$.

My attempt:

There are two triangles that are separated by the diagonal in the square, so the triangle that we are considering should be in one of them. So that triangle should have an area less than $0.5$ square units, as otherwise the sum of the areas of the two triangles is greater then the area if the square containing them. This is where I get stuck... how do I convert this area statement into a length statement?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What are your attempts on solving this question ? Did you draw some diagrams ? Where are you stuck? Please share so someone can help

Comment: Here the way i tried to solve it...there are two triangles that are separated by the diagonal in the square...so the triangle that we are considering should be in one of them....so that triangle should  have an area less than 0.5 square units....from here i wasn't able to solve it...so can you please help me to construct the next portion of the answer???

Comment: Please edit your question and include this

Comment: I'm afraid..wt should i include???

Comment: Area arguments alone can't solve the problem. The triangle with side lengths $1,1,1.99$ has area $0.0994$.

Comment: @K.vindi you should include an explanation of how you tried to solve the problem, just like you gave in the comments. You should also try to use full sentences.

Comment: The triangle could have points on three sides of the square, so that it crosses over both diagonals. So it does not have to be inside one of the two triangles formed by the diagonals of the square. The area of the triangle described in the question will be less than $1/2,$ but not for the reason you stated.